# create a new model instance version instead of update

Tags: django, save, models

I have a model with a version field - autocreate timestamp.
When a model instance is being saved I want to create a new instance with a new timestamp instead of updating the old model instance.

Is it possible?

I thought of overriding the model save() method but I don't know how to create a new instance without creating a infinite save() loop.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could set `self.id = None` in the overridden `save` method - then in the super method, Django would do an INSERT rather than an UPDATE.

Or, as pointed out in the documentation [here](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/ref/models/instances/#forcing-an-insert-or-update), you could use the `force_insert=True` parameter in the call to `save`, which does the same thing.